# Extra pixels are being added to span element

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why but 2 extra pixels are added to the height of a span element.  Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span style="font-size:20px;line-height: 20px">
    test
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome debugger tools the span has a height of 22 pixels.  If I change the test element to a div the extra pixels go away.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="font-size:20px;line-height: 20px">
    test
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a fiddle with the span and the div elements

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1kp25jpz/)

Comment: You'll want to explain your question better. Let us know how your span element actually looks right now, where the extra pixels are located, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css - inline elements ignoring line-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609227/css-inline-elements-ignoring-line-height)

Comment: The `span` is an inline element, so the browser will calculate height based on the size of the content.

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ , it is easier for people to help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened, because `span` is an `inline` element and it's `height` is set to `auto`. Set `display` property to `inline-block`, for example, and `span` will take exactly the `height` you want it to take.

```html
<div style="font-size:20px;line-height: 20px">
    test
</div>
    
<span style="display:inline-block;font-size:20px;line-height: 20px">
    test
</span>
```