# Div Different Height Than Span

Tags: css

I have a issue with a div's height not matching the span's below it:

https://jsfiddle.net/daneren2005/f2bmfkxg/:

```
<div class="outerDiv" style="line-height: 1.33">
    <div class="innerDiv" style="font-size: 68.57px; font-family: libre baskerville;">
        <span>Large Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The innerDiv's height is 91 which is correct (68.56 x 1.33 = 91.19).  The span's height is 86 though.  I have no idea where the height came from.  I have a HTML -> SVG converter that mostly works except for in some edge cases like this.  I just need to understand where this discrepancy comes from so I can handle it in my calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `span` element is an inline element. For these instances, change the `span` to and `inline-block` display:

```
span {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's some more reading:
[css - inline elements ignoring line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609227/css-inline-elements-ignoring-line-height)

Here's the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f2bmfkxg/1/

Comment: Alright so where is 86 as the height coming from?  It seems to have no relation to the font-size entered.

Comment: Fonts still have inherent line-height (leading). If you look at the bounding box in a web inspector, you can see the space above the text and it ends just below the descender (in your case the g in Large). If fonts did not have this as part of the font specification, lines would run together. Change the font to `Arial` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `div`'s line-height to 1 you will see that it does not affect `span`'s height.

It happens because inline elements like `span` take only required amount of space to render them.