# In Firefox, why the height of text is bigger than font-size i set

Tags: html, css, fonts

I set font-size to 14px for text in a span element. but when i check the box model in devTool, the height for this span is 15px height. Why this will happen? 
Here is my screenshot for all html and css[image]

And here is for box model

[image]

As pic shows, the font-size is 14px , while box model show 15px.

PS, my OS is mac.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could try adding the property outline: none to the span.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609227/css-inline-elements-ignoring-line-height